# MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback in MERN page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am getting this error will constructing a MERN page and couldn't get the get format. Here is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserModel = require("./models/Users");

const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://User:<password>@cluster0.o6pjbpq.mongodb.net/Database?retryWrites=true&w=majority" //Leave this part i have checked the mongoose.connect and no change.
);

app.get("/getUsers", (req, res) => {
  UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});

app.post("/createUser", async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  const newUser = new UserModel(user);
  await newUser.save();

  res.json(user);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("SERVER RUNS PERFECTLY!");
});
```

I was expecting to get 200 OK and I am getting 500 Internal Server Error. And in the response page I am getting:

````
MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback
    at Function.find (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2110:11)
    at C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\index.js:16:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at cors (C:\Users\Fikirte Amare\Desktop\website\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)```
````

Comment: Did you read the error message? The method no longer accepts a callback, so _why are you passing one_?! If you're coming from an earlier version, follow the appropriate [migration guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support).

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose no longer supports callbacks, you can read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support)

You can try the following code on your get request:

```
app.get("/getUsers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await UserModel.find({});
    res.json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error log and the comments/answers others have provided, you appear to be using Mongoose v7 or later, which explains the presence of this error in your console.

```
MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback
```

One of the backwards-breaking changes introduced in [Mongoose v7](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/releases/tag/7.0.0) dropped callback support. Simply put, many Mongoose functions now return promises instead of accepting callbacks.

[image]

Viewing the complete list, you will see that `Model.find` is among those listed.

> Unfortunately, many of the code snippets, tutorials, and even templates/repositories currently available have yet to reflect this change, which can lead to confusion, especially for newbies who aren't yet familiar with the ins and outs of Mongoose.

There are two ways to fix the error you are receiving.

1. Refactor your callbacks to use `async/await` syntax.
2. If that won't work, instead, use promises, ergo, `promise.then().catch().finally()`.

If you need help refactoring a legacy codebase, the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support) suggests using this [conversion tool](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/tools/callback-to-async-await). NOTE: Your mileage may vary.

*Example using `async/await`*

```js
// Before
app.get('/getUsers', (req, res) => {
    UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json(result)
        }
    })
})

// After
app.get('/getUsers', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await UserModel.find({})
        res.json(result)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json(err)
    }
})
```

*Example using `promise.then().catch().finally()`*

```js
// Before
app.get('/getUsers', (req, res) => {
    UserModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json(result)
        }
    })
})


// After
app.get('/getUsers', (req, res) => {
    UserModel.find({})
        .then((result) => {
            res.json(result)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.json(err)
        })
})
```